# установка изображения в ImageView из массива в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

имеется Activity, которое должно при нажатии на кнопку менять изображение в ImageView на случайное из массива, но при переходе переходе в него, приложение вылетает. Помогите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?
java class:

```
  public class Main2Activity_R extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2__r);
    }
    BitmapDrawable img1 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rice1);
    BitmapDrawable img0 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hqdefault1);
    BitmapDrawable img2 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s);
    Drawable drawableArray[] = new Drawable[] { img0, img1, img2 };
    int n;

    public void changeImage(View view) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        n = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * drawableArray.length);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawableArray[n]);
    }
}
```

xml:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main2Activity_R">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
    android:onClick="changeImage"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="192dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/hqdefault1" />
```

Logcat:

```
03-28 12:25:46.567 20982-20982/com.example.logo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.logo, PID: 20982
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.logo/com.example.logo.Main2Activity_R}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2131)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:543)
        at com.example.logo.Main2Activity_R.<init>(Main2Activity_R.java:17)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-28 12:25:47.758 20982-20982/com.example.logo I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20982 SIG: 9
```

Main2Activity_R.java:17 - это строка "BitmapDrawable img1 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rice1);"

Comment: Отредактировал, теперь вроде все есть

Comment: вам нужно закрывающюю фигурную скобку после метода `setContentView();` перенести после `Drawable drawableArray[] = new Drawable[] { img0, img1, img2 };` , а сам массив `drawableArray` из локальной переменной вынести в поле класса, чтобы он был доступен и в методе `changeImage()`. Дело в том, что этой скобкой вы завершили колбэк `onCreate()` и дальнейший код принимается компилятором за инициализацию полей класса, но он не может ее завершить, так как идет обращение к ресурсам, а они на этом этапе недоступны

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за подсказку, искал решение для аналогичной задачи. С учетом правок
pavlofff на текущей версии андроид студио получил такой рабочий код:

```
Drawable[] drawableArray;
int n;

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_add_user_book_2);

@SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables") BitmapDrawable img1 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cover_challenger);
@SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables") BitmapDrawable img0 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cover_angel);
@SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables") BitmapDrawable img2 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cover_alien);
drawableArray = new Drawable[] { img0, img1, img2 };
```

}

```
public void coursePageImage(View view) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coursePageImage);
    n = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * drawableArray.length);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawableArray[n]);
}
```

}